# Сеть и интернет на Virtual Box, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Нужно:
Чтобы с хоста была доступна по локальной сети гостевая ОС, а именно Ubuntu Server с webmin, а также доступ в интернет с гостевой ОС.

Проблема:
Ставлю Ubuntu Server, изначально интернет работает, но, естественно, сети нет. Пытаюсь настроить сеть, меняю 1-й адаптер на Виртуальный адаптер хоста, второй на NAT. В `/etc/network/interfaces` прописываю

```
 # The hostonly network interface
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.56.101
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.56.0
  broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Сеть вроде как появляется. Если прописать `ping 192.168.56.101` на хосте - все окей. Но интернет на госте уже отсутствует.

Как правильно настроить это дело, и в чем конкретно может быть проблема?

Comment: это точно решается двумя путями:

1. Добавление host-only и nat-адаптеров
2. Добавление bridged adapter, который заставит ВМ зарегистрироваться как полноценное сетевое устройство, хоть и с тем же MAC-адресом

Вы пытаетесь реализовать превый вариант, и, очевидно, ВМ пытается использовать первый адаптер для отсылку пакетов в интернет, а он "кончается" машиной-хостом (а ей нужен второй).

Comment: У меня в Windows 7 в VirtualBox с ubuntu в

     Настройки->сеть->Адаптер 1


стоит 

     Сетевой мост

и `ping 8.8.8.8` из гостя  в Internet работает (браузер и все остальные клиенты, а также обмен между гостем и хостом тоже работают).

Comment: @Etki, можно поподробнее, как поправить? Местами поменять?))
@avp, менял, не работает..Что должно быть в /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: @Евгений Шилин, если грубо, то да. Вообще я бы файл interfaces не трогал вообще. У меня у самого всё на сетевых мостах висит, всё ок, может просто dhcp нет и локалка не выдает айпишник?

Comment: Насколько помню, я вообще ничего не настраивал. Поставил несколько лет назад "из коробки" (может и отвечал на какие-то вопросы, но не помню). 

А interfaces:

    avp@avp-xub11:hash_misc$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
    
    avp@avp-xub11:hash_misc$

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы. Сеть так и не получилось настроить)). Теперь юзаю ubuntu рядом с виндой.

Comment: @Евгений Шилин, какие требования есть к сети? Просто чтобы виртуалка интернет видела?

Comment: @Евгений Шилин, а какую версию VirtualBox Вы пытались использовать?


У меня со всеми, начиная с 4.3.13 постоянно возникали разные проблемы, так что я уже давно ее не обновляю, работаю с 4.3.12.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

это точно решается двумя путями: 1. Добавление host-only и nat-адаптеров 2. Добавление bridged adapter, который заставит ВМ зарегистрироваться как полноценное сетевое устройство, хоть и с тем же MAC-адресом Вы пытаетесь реализовать превый вариант, и, очевидно, ВМ пытается использовать первый адаптер для отсылку пакетов в интернет, а он "кончается" машиной-хостом (а ей нужен второй).